# Plectrum Guitar music sheet

Tags: notation, sheet-music, acoustic-guitar

Can someone tell me the meaning of this bar of music. It says harmoinic pick on 17th fret but the notation is on E. Should'nt that on a higher octave A? As 17th fret would be A in standard tuning.

[image]

Comment: could they mean fret the e (octave, 12th fret) and play a harmonic on 17? what is that called a pinch harmonic, or secondary harmonic.  i don't have my guitar with me so can't see what note that would produce.

Comment: @b3ko can't be a pinch according to the notation. There's secondo being played at the same time.

Comment: What piece is this. Would help to hear what it sounds like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to a page with a chart of where the harmonics are on the guitar. According to that chart a harmonic which occurs at the 17th fret would be an interval three octaves above the open string.

http://totalguitarist.com/lessons/theory/harmonics/intro/#2

Comment: Web links go away.  Please add the chart to your answer.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of detail in the link.

Comment: I will be back regarding @pro 's request for the chart.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having trouble finding a good harmonic on 17th fret. 19th sounds good, but if anything, 17th will give a 10th interval from the fundamental - G# on an E.

Comment: No, G# is on the 16th fret (16 = 12 + 4), and as Lars said, 17th fret (that's 12+5) gives you E three octaves above the open string. Indeed it might be tricky to play, for instance you need to be careful about the plucking hand placement – it's easier if you pluck closer to the bridge.